Android Management API - How to use configurationVariables in ManagedConfigurationTemplate
I want to install an app with a managed configuration template (defined by the embedded managed configuration iFrame) and provide a unique device ID that gets included in the managed configuration for the device. There appears to be a mechanism for this named configurationVariables but I haven't found documentation on how to use it.
I have one policy per device. In that policy there would be something like this...
{
    "applications": [
        {
            "packageName": "com.example",
            "managedConfigurationTemplate": {
                "templateId": "abc123",
                "configurationVariables": {
                    "deviceId": "123456789"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

How does the Android App get the deviceId value?

The android app can retrieve the managed configuration values using RestrictionsManager. You may check this link for more information.
